# Google Sign In Failure

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-signin, google-play-games

I am using Google Play Games Sign In implementation in my app but it fails with the error below:

```
 java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient: int com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.zzabd() failed to verify: int com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.zzabd():
```

the error occurs in this part of the code:

```
public void performGooglePlayServicesConnection() {
    GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN_GOOGLE_PLAY_GAMES);
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested workaround in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28032719/5832311) is to clean out the `build` folder resolved the problem.

> Running a `gradle` clean task was not clearing out my build folder all the way. I had to do it manually, but clean may work for some people.

It is also recommended that if `Clear project` doesn't work, try with `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` -> `Invalidate and Restart`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error.I missed to Configure Google API Console project.
So **Configure Google API Console project** following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)
and specify your app's package name when prompted. You will also need to provide the **SHA-1 hash** of your signing certificate. See Authenticating Your Client for information.