# What causes java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

While uing Moshi converter, adding a few more, causes the following error. Not sure where or why it says

> Rejecting invocation, expected 81 argument registers, method signature
> has 82 or more

I'm not limiting it anywhere. Can anyone help me get rid of this error?

> 2021-09-20 15:50:22.701 26917-5331/com.nnapps.currencyconverter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
> Process: com.nnapps.currencyconverter, PID: 26917
> java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.nnapps.currencyconverter.data.models.RatesJsonAdapter: com.nnapps.currencyconverter.data.models.Rates com.nnapps.currencyconverter.data.models.RatesJsonAdapter.fromJson(com.squareup.moshi.JsonReader) failed to verify: com.nnapps.currencyconverter.data.models.Rates com.nnapps.currencyconverter.data.models.RatesJsonAdapter.fromJson(com.squareup.moshi.JsonReader): [0x2FE3] Rejecting invocation, expected 81 argument registers, method signature has 82 or more (declaration of 'com.nnapps.currencyconverter.data.models.RatesJsonAdapter' appears in /data/app/~~z4ivoR2x0ywjtOjcAdAGhA==/com.nnapps.currencyconverter-fq07cpkD73GiucXGVon54Q==/base.apk!classes10.dex)
> at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
> at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(Util.java:553)
> at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$1.create(StandardJsonAdapters.java:61)
> at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:145)
> at com.nnapps.currencyconverter.data.models.CurrencyResponseJsonAdapter.(CurrencyResponseJsonAdapter.kt:31)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
> at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(Util.java:577)
> at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$1.create(StandardJsonAdapters.java:61)
> at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:145)
> at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:105)
> at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(MoshiConverterFactory.java:89)
> at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:362)
> at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:345)
> at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:124)
> at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:85)
> at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
> at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
> at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
> at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
> at $Proxy2.getRates(Unknown Source)
> at com.nnapps.currencyconverter.main.DefaultMainRepository.getRates(DefaultMainRepository.kt:16)
> at com.nnapps.currencyconverter.main.DefaultMainUseCase.getRates(DefaultMainUseCase.kt:11)
> at com.nnapps.currencyconverter.main.MainViewModel$convert$1.invokeSuspend(MainViewModel.kt:50)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Rates(
    @Json(name = "AED")
    val aED: Double,
    @Json(name = "AFN")
    val aFN: Double,
    @Json(name = "ALL")
    val aLL: Double,
    @Json(name = "AMD")
    val aMD: Double,
    @Json(name = "ANG")
    val aNG: Double,
    @Json(name = "AOA")
    val aOA: Double,
    @Json(name = "ARS")
    val aRS: Double,
    @Json(name = "AUD")
    val aUD: Double,
    @Json(name = "AWG")
    val aWG: Double,
    @Json(name = "AZN")
    val aZN: Double,
    @Json(name = "BAM")
    val bAM: Double,
    @Json(name = "BBD")
    val bBD: Double,
    @Json(name = "BDT")
    val bDT: Double,
    @Json(name = "BGN")
    val bGN: Double,
    @Json(name = "BHD")
    val bHD: Double,
    @Json(name = "BIF")
    val bIF: Double,
    @Json(name = "BMD")
    val bMD: Double,
    @Json(name = "BND")
    val bND: Double,
    @Json(name = "BOB")
    val bOB: Double,
    @Json(name = "BRL")
    val bRL: Double,
    @Json(name = "BSD")
    val bSD: Double,
    @Json(name = "BTC")
    val bTC: Double,
    @Json(name = "BTN")
    val bTN: Double,
    @Json(name = "BWP")
    val bWP: Double,
    @Json(name = "BYN")
    val bYN: Double,
    @Json(name = "BYR")
    val bYR: Double,
    @Json(name = "BZD")
    val bZD: Double,
    @Json(name = "CAD")
    val cAD: Double,
    @Json(name = "CDF")
    val cDF: Double,
    @Json(name = "CHF")
    val cHF: Double,
    @Json(name = "CLF")
    val cLF: Double,
    @Json(name = "CLP")
    val cLP: Double,
    @Json(name = "CNY")
    val cNY: Double,
    @Json(name = "COP")
    val cOP: Double,
    @Json(name = "CRC")
    val cRC: Double,
    @Json(name = "CUC")
    val cUC: Double,
    @Json(name = "CUP")
    val cUP: Double,
    @Json(name = "CVE")
    val cVE: Double,
    @Json(name = "CZK")
    val cZK: Double,
    @Json(name = "DJF")
    val dJF: Double,
    @Json(name = "DKK")
    val dKK: Double,
    @Json(name = "DOP")
    val dOP: Double,
    @Json(name = "DZD")
    val dZD: Double,
    @Json(name = "EGP")
    val eGP: Double,
    @Json(name = "ERN")
    val eRN: Double,
    @Json(name = "ETB")
    val eTB: Double,
    @Json(name = "EUR")
    val eUR: Double,
    @Json(name = "FJD")
    val fJD: Double,
    @Json(name = "FKP")
    val fKP: Double,
    @Json(name = "GBP")
    val gBP: Double,
    @Json(name = "GEL")
    val gEL: Double,
    @Json(name = "GGP")
    val gGP: Double,
    @Json(name = "GHS")
    val gHS: Double,
    @Json(name = "GIP")
    val gIP: Double,
    @Json(name = "GMD")
    val gMD: Double,
    @Json(name = "GNF")
    val gNF: Double,
    @Json(name = "GTQ")
    val gTQ: Double,
    @Json(name = "GYD")
    val gYD: Double,
    @Json(name = "HKD")
    val hKD: Double,
    @Json(name = "HNL")
    val hNL: Double,
    @Json(name = "HRK")
    val hRK: Double,
    @Json(name = "HTG")
    val hTG: Double,
    @Json(name = "HUF")
    val hUF: Double,
    @Json(name = "IDR")
    val iDR: Double,
    @Json(name = "ILS")
    val iLS: Double,
    @Json(name = "IMP")
    val iMP: Double,
    @Json(name = "INR")
    val iNR: Double,
    @Json(name = "IQD")
    val iQD: Double,
    @Json(name = "IRR")
    val iRR: Double,
    @Json(name = "ISK")
    val iSK: Double,
    @Json(name = "JEP")
    val jEP: Double,
    @Json(name = "JMD")
    val jMD: Double,
    @Json(name = "JOD")
    val jOD: Double,
    @Json(name = "JPY")
    val jPY: Double,
    @Json(name = "KES")
    val kES: Double,
    @Json(name = "KGS")
    val kGS: Double,
    @Json(name = "KHR")
    val kHR: Double,
    @Json(name = "KMF")
    val kMF: Double,
    @Json(name = "KPW")
    val kPW: Double,
    @Json(name = "KRW")
    val kRW: Double,
    @Json(name = "KWD")
    val kWD: Double,
    @Json(name = "KYD")
    val kYD: Double,
    @Json(name = "KZT")
    val kZT: Double,
    @Json(name = "LAK")
    val lAK: Double,
    @Json(name = "LBP")
    val lBP: Double,
    @Json(name = "LKR")
    val lKR: Double,
    @Json(name = "LRD")
    val lRD: Double,
    @Json(name = "LSL")
    val lSL: Double,
    @Json(name = "LTL")
    val lTL: Double,
    @Json(name = "LVL")
    val lVL: Double,
    @Json(name = "LYD")
    val lYD: Double,
    @Json(name = "MAD")
    val mAD: Double,
    @Json(name = "MDL")
    val mDL: Double,
    @Json(name = "MGA")
    val mGA: Double,
    @Json(name = "MKD")
    val mKD: Double,
    @Json(name = "MMK")
    val mMK: Double,
    @Json(name = "MNT")
    val mNT: Double,
    @Json(name = "MOP")
    val mOP: Double,
    @Json(name = "MRO")
    val mRO: Double,
    @Json(name = "MUR")
    val mUR: Double,
    @Json(name = "MVR")
    val mVR: Double,
    @Json(name = "MWK")
    val mWK: Double,
    @Json(name = "MXN")
    val mXN: Double,
    @Json(name = "MYR")
    val mYR: Double,
    @Json(name = "MZN")
    val mZN: Double,
    @Json(name = "NAD")
    val nAD: Double,
    @Json(name = "NGN")
    val nGN: Double,
    @Json(name = "NIO")
    val nIO: Double,
    @Json(name = "NOK")
    val nOK: Double,
    @Json(name = "NPR")
    val nPR: Double,
    @Json(name = "NZD")
    val nZD: Double,
    @Json(name = "OMR")
    val oMR: Double,
    @Json(name = "PAB")
    val pAB: Double,
    @Json(name = "PEN")
    val pEN: Double,
    @Json(name = "PGK")
    val pGK: Double,
    @Json(name = "PHP")
    val pHP: Double,
    @Json(name = "PKR")
    val pKR: Double,
    @Json(name = "PLN")
    val pLN: Double,
    @Json(name = "PYG")
    val pYG: Double,
    @Json(name = "QAR")
    val qAR: Double,
    @Json(name = "RON")
    val rON: Double,
    @Json(name = "RSD")
    val rSD: Double,
    @Json(name = "RUB")
    val rUB: Double,
    @Json(name = "RWF")
    val rWF: Double,
    @Json(name = "SAR")
    val sAR: Double,
    @Json(name = "SBD")
    val sBD: Double,
    @Json(name = "SCR")
    val sCR: Double,
    @Json(name = "SDG")
    val sDG: Double,
    @Json(name = "SEK")
    val sEK: Double,
    @Json(name = "SGD")
    val sGD: Double,
    @Json(name = "SHP")
    val sHP: Double,
    @Json(name = "SLL")
    val sLL: Double,
    @Json(name = "SOS")
    val sOS: Double,
    @Json(name = "SRD")
    val sRD: Double,
    @Json(name = "STD")
    val sTD: Double,
    @Json(name = "SVC")
    val sVC: Double,
    @Json(name = "SYP")
    val sYP: Double,
    @Json(name = "SZL")
    val sZL: Double,
    @Json(name = "THB")
    val tHB: Double,
    @Json(name = "TJS")
    val tJS: Double,
    @Json(name = "TMT")
    val tMT: Double,
    @Json(name = "TND")
    val tND: Double,
    @Json(name = "TOP")
    val tOP: Double,
    @Json(name = "TRY")
    val tRY: Double,
    @Json(name = "TTD")
    val tTD: Double,
    @Json(name = "TWD")
    val tWD: Double,
    @Json(name = "TZS")
    val tZS: Double,
    @Json(name = "UAH")
    val uAH: Double,
    @Json(name = "UGX")
    val uGX: Double,
    @Json(name = "USD")
    val uSD: Double,
    @Json(name = "UYU")
    val uYU: Double,
    @Json(name = "UZS")
    val uZS: Double,
    @Json(name = "VEF")
    val vEF: Double,
    @Json(name = "VND")
    val vND: Double,
    @Json(name = "VUV")
    val vUV: Double,
    @Json(name = "WST")
    val wST: Double,
    @Json(name = "XAF")
    val xAF: Double,
    @Json(name = "XAG")
    val xAG: Double,
    @Json(name = "XAU")
    val xAU: Double,
    @Json(name = "XCD")
    val xCD: Double,
    @Json(name = "XDR")
    val xDR: Double,
    @Json(name = "XOF")
    val xOF: Double,
    @Json(name = "XPF")
    val xPF: Double,
    @Json(name = "YER")
    val yER: Double,
    @Json(name = "ZAR")
    val zAR: Double,
    @Json(name = "ZMK")
    val zMK: Double,
    @Json(name = "ZMW")
    val zMW: Double,
    @Json(name = "ZWL")
    val zWL: Double,
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031905/java-lang-verifyerror-verifier-rejected-class-on-lollipop-when-using-release-ap

Comment: Those solutions Unfortunately didn't work for me

Comment: Answer for that question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72015587/unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-class-rates-registering-an-instancecre/72742519#72742519

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, after tracking it down I found that I updated some dependencies in the Gradle file; which caused this crash.
Go to the Gradle file and see what last change you made there and rollback or search for what has changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).