# Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class Rates. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem

Tags: android, kotlin, http, retrofit2

I am working with a currency API and whenever I am trying to call API I get this error from retrofit:

```
2022-04-26 15:28:25.965 25903-25928/com.gmail.[packageName].currencyapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.gmail.[packageName].currencyapplication, PID: 25903
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class com.gmail.[packageName].currencyapplication.feature_currency.domain.model.Rates. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

Here is my Retrofit API class

```
interface CurrencyApi {

    @GET("/{date}?access_key="+Constants.API_KEY)
    suspend fun getCurrencyResponse(
        @Path("date") date:String,
        @Query("base") base:String,
    ):Response<CurrencyResponse>
}
```

And here are my model classes that I created using json to data class plugin

```
data class CurrencyResponse(
    val base: String,
    val date: String,
    val historical: Boolean,
    val rates: Rates,
    val success: Boolean,
    val timestamp: Int
)

data class Rates(
    val AED: Double,
    val AFN: Double,
    val ALL: Double,
    val AMD: Double,
    val ANG: Double,
    val AOA: Double,
    val ARS: Double,
    val AUD: Double,
    val AWG: Double,
    val AZN: Double,
    val BAM: Double,
    val BBD: Double,
    val BDT: Double,
    val BGN: Double,
    val BHD: Double,
    val BIF: Double,
    val BMD: Double,
    val BND: Double,
    val BOB: Double,
    val BRL: Double,
    ... More vals 
)
```

And here is my retrofit builder:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofitInstance() : Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideCurrencyApi(
    retrofitInstance:Retrofit
):CurrencyApi = retrofitInstance.create(CurrencyApi::class.java)
```

Some things I already did:

- removing suspend modifier from Api
- removing Response and leaving only
  `CurrencyResponse` in return data type

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately i'm also get this problem and lost 1 day to solve it. And solve is pretty simple...
For some reason kotlin data classes can contain **only 127 args**. I think in your data class more than 127 args. Thats why you getting that error.

The answer is:
**just remove some vals.**

Comment: it's only one val, `data class NetworkPagingList<T>(
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<T>
)`.

Comment: here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76109452/unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-class-registering-an-instancecreator-w

Answer (score 2):

If this error appears on release .apk or .aab try to remove/comment this from gradle.properties

```
android.enableR8.fullMode=true
```

Comment: it's not a solution

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately i'm also get this problem and lost 1 day to solve it.
> And solve is pretty simple... For some reason kotlin data classes can
> contain only 127 args. I think in your data class more than 127 args.
> Thats why you getting that error.
>
> The answer is: just remove some vals.
> [Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72742519/12931715) by @Spectator

You have two options.

1. Break down the response data class into two (**RatesAToL** and **RatesMToZ**) and make two requests to the API.
2. Converting the JSON object (conversion_rates) into a list of objects
   `Rate(val code: String, val amount: Double)`
   . This can be done using a Moshi custom adapter. Code sample here [Custom Moshi adapter](https://gist.github.com/ayiaware/86155c8d99782add04439619f7fc301e)

   ```
    class MoshiJsonAdapter : JsonAdapter<InfoAndRatesResponse>() {

    @FromJson
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): InfoAndRatesResponse {

    reader.beginObject()

    var result = ""
    var timeLastUpdateUnix = 0
    var timeLastUpdateUtc = ""
    var timeNextUpdateUnix = 0
    var timeNextUpdateUtc = ""
    var baseCode = ""
    val rates = mutableListOf<Rate>()

    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        when (reader.nextName()) {
            "result" -> result = reader.nextString()
            "time_last_update_unix" -> timeLastUpdateUnix = reader.nextInt()
            "time_last_update_utc" -> timeLastUpdateUtc = reader.nextString()
            "time_next_update_unix" -> timeNextUpdateUnix = reader.nextInt()
            "time_next_update_utc" -> timeNextUpdateUtc = reader.nextString()
            "base_code" -> baseCode = reader.nextString()
            "conversion_rates" -> {

                reader.beginObject()

                while (reader.peek() != JsonReader.Token.END_OBJECT) {

                    val code = reader.nextName()

                    val amount = when (code) {
                        baseCode -> reader.nextInt().toDouble()
                        else -> reader.nextDouble()
                    }

                    val infoBaseCode = baseCode

                    Timber.tag("MyTag")
                        .d(" code $code amount $amount infoBaseCode $infoBaseCode")

                    rates.add(
                        Rate(
                            code = code,
                            amount = amount,
                            infoBaseCode = infoBaseCode,
                        )
                    )
                }
                reader.endObject()
            }
            else -> reader.skipValue()
        }
    }
    reader.endObject()

    return InfoAndRatesResponse(
        result = result,
        timeLastUpdateUnix = timeLastUpdateUnix,
        timeLastUpdateUtc = timeLastUpdateUtc,
        timeNextUpdateUnix = timeNextUpdateUnix,
        timeNextUpdateUtc = timeNextUpdateUtc,
        baseCode = baseCode,
        rates = rates
     )
    }

   @ToJson
    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: 
    InfoAndRatesResponse?) {
    throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
   }
   ```