# Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gson, android-r8

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class com.arch.example.network.models.NetworkPagingList. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
                    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:228)
                    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
                    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
                    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
                    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
                    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
                    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Abstract class can't be instantiated! Class name: com.arch.example.network.models.NetworkPagingList
                    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator.assertInstantiable(UnsafeAllocator.java:120)
                    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$1.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:49)
                    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:225)
                    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212) 
                    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40) 
                    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27) 
                    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243) 
                    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153) 
                    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519) 
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

The entitity:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class NetworkPagingList<T>(
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<T>
)
```

Where it's used:

```
    @GET("worker/shifts")
    suspend fun getShifts(
        @Query("page") page: Int,
        @Query("perPage") perPage: Int
    ): NetworkPagingList<NetworkShift>
```

So what's wrong here exactly?

It was working ok previously, but seems with the most newest gradle plugin for Android stopped working with release build, something mb with R8

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `@Keep` in your data class as follow:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

@Keep
data class NetworkPagingList<T>(
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<T>
)
```

Comment: but the class is not removed, it would be a different error

Answer (score 3):

Ad below line in your progaurd rules file may resolve your issue

```
-keepclassmembers class com.arch.example.network.models.NetworkPagingList {
    public <init>();
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why do I have to keep it if I specified `@SerializedName("data")`?

Comment: The error you are getting is exactly related to GSON being able to construct instance of `com.arch.example.network.models.NetworkPagingList`. You could take a look at the actual DEX code generated for this class, as that affects the allocation performed by GSON. You can use Apktool. See https://github.com/google/gson/blob/2658aca66a1d0f097794a5ad5eb33c095a8f8d5d/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/ConstructorConstructor.java#L373 using https://github.com/google/gson/blob/742fd50ff74350462d8dcf80941efce219e187dd/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/UnsafeAllocator.java#L30

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using these steps.

1. add `@Keep` to data class
2. add this to **proguard-rule.pro**

```
 # Keep generic signature of Call, Response (R8 full mode strips signatures from non-kept items).
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response

 # With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not
 # kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument
 # is used.
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

Answer (score 1):

Add whole models package or specific class to proguard file.

```
-keep class your.package.model.** { *; }
```

or

```
-keep class your.package.model.your.class
```

(replace your.package.model with your own)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove `abstract keyword` from my generic data class model.