# Keep getting error on android studio project java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.firestore.v1.Value:

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.sellit, PID: 21402
                                                                                                    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.firestore.v1.Value: void com.google.firestore.v1.Value.mergeGeoPointValue(com.google.type.LatLng) failed to verify: void com.google.firestore.v1.Value.mergeGeoPointValue(com.google.type.LatLng): [0x19] register v4 has type Precise Reference: com.google.type.LatLng but expected Reference: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite
                                                                                                     void com.google.firestore.v1.Value.mergeTimestampValue(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp) failed to verify: void com.google.firestore.v1.Value.mergeTimestampValue(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp): [0x19] register v4 has type Precise Reference: com.google.protobuf.Timestamp but expected Reference: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite (declaration of 'com.google.firestore.v1.Value' appears in /data/app/~~f45OKSRu4zvHtUGPkqm61Q==/com.example.sellit-ypy_xq8iBTIqr4GuT8n7Ag==/base.apk!classes8.dex)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firestore.v1.Value.getDefaultInstance(Value.java:1862)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue$FieldsDefaultEntryHolder.<clinit>(MapValue.java:29)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.dynamicMethod(MapValue.java:421)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.dynamicMethod(GeneratedMessageLite.java:308)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.buildMessageInfo(GeneratedMessageLite.java:376)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.java:60)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory$CompositeMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:144)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory.createSchema(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:56)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:91)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:105)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.makeImmutable(GeneratedMessageLite.java:226)
                                                                                                        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.registerDefaultInstance(GeneratedMessageLite.java:411)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.<clinit>(MapValue.java:466)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.newBuilder(MapValue.java:228)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseMap(UserDataReader.java:290)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseData(UserDataReader.java:251)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.convertAndParseDocumentData(UserDataReader.java:232)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseSetData(UserDataReader.java:75)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:167)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:147)
                                                                                                        at com.example.sellit.SignUpActivity$2.onComplete(SignUpActivity.java:79)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I am making an android app that uses firebase firestore for database. However I get the above error everytime I press the signup button.

I am calling this function in my signupactivity.java class

```
firebaseFirestore.collection(DATA_USERS).document(firebaseAuth.getUid()).set(user);
```

I have no idea how to fix this please help..

Ive tried:

in my build.gradle

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.0'){



        exclude module: 'protolite-well-known-types'
        exclude module: 'protobuf-javalite'
        exclude module: 'protobuf-java'
        exclude module: 'protobuf-java-util'
        //exclude module: "com.google.protobuf"
        exclude module:'protobuf-lite'
        exclude module:'proto-google-common-protos'

    }
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031905/java-lang-verifyerror-verifier-rejected-class-on-lollipop-when-using-release-ap) will help.

Comment: sorry that didnt help